# Getting only one notification result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

So I have a notification system, here's the tables layout

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| from_user | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| to_user   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And this is what one row looks like

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------+
| id | from_user | to_user | type   | date |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------+
| 32 | allex     | scott   | hgjghj | NULL |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------+
```

Now here's how I'm getting the results

```
    //Check if any records of notifications exists & loop em' back
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE to_user = :user");
$stmt->bindValue(':user', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$notifications = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $notifications[] =  array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'from_user' => $row['from_user'],
        'to_user' => $row['to_user'],
        'type' => $row['type'],
        'date' => $row['date']
    );
}
```

And now finally my issue, say I had another row, and the type was different, what happens is once I loop the query I get the same `type` returned throughout the whole, so instead of

```
Alelx hgjghj scott,
```

and say I had another result that said

```
Alelx ghfjhgj scott
```

I wouldn't be able to see it because the `Type` from the first result ends up being "dominant". Any help would be great.

Comment: There is only one row in Database...

Comment: Well assuming I was to add another result @OzanKurt

Comment: The first element in the array isn't "dominant". It's the first element in the array. If you want the second element, you need to reference the _second_ element `$notifications[1]['type']` rather than the first _first_ element (`[0]`). This doesn't really have anything to do with sql or mysql. You'd get the same behavior with a static array.

Comment: Well its all user input. So you're saying I'd have to list _all_ my queries? Isn't that why I have a loop? @spencer7593

Comment: @user302975: You show one query execution. You show a loop that fetches all rows returned by that query, populating a freshly initialized array. First row fetched goes into first element in the array [0], second row fetched goes into second element [1], etc. If you were to loop back through this same code a second time (not shown in the code you posted), the existing array would be reinitialized again, `$notifications = array();`, wiping out the current contents of that array. We don't see what you are doing with the array once it's populated.

Comment: @user302975: No, I'm not saying you have to list _all_ your queries. (I only see one query.) "Isn't that why I have a loop?" It looks like the purpose of your loop is to fetch _all_ the rows returned by the single execution of a query, and store each of the rows as a new element added to an array.

Comment: I'm trying to select _all_ the rows from the notifications table where the usernames equal. With other parts of my code I use the same method as posted above, but I just can't retrieve them, I'd usually get an array with `0` and encased in that array is other arrays. Know how I can get that? @spencer7593

Comment: Perhaps the issue you are having isn't with mysql at all. Seems more like you're having difficulty processing a multi-dimensional array. After $notifications is populated, you can loop through the elements using a `foreach` loop. e.g. `foreach ($notifications as $notification) { echo $notification['type']; }`

Answer (score 1):

According to your code your $notifications array will look like this:

```
Array
 0 => (... type=>'hgjghj' ...)
 1 => (... type=>'ghfjhgj' ...)
```

Every row of your DB will get another element to this array.
So, you need to loop through that array and see what values you get.

Comment: But that's not what's happening. All I get is `hgjghj`, I call it like this `$notifications[0]['type']`

Comment: @user302975: If there's a second entry in the array, that would be referenced as `$notifications[` **`1`** `]['type']`, repeated references to the same first element `[0]` of the array are going to return that same value.

Comment: Well what's happening is I get `Notice: Undefined index` when I try to do `$notifications['type']`, so essentially how would I just get all? @spencer7593

Comment: You can loop through it of course. the $notifications[0] you use is just the first record in your array.